How to Align Preprocessor Directives (#) with Code Blocks Using clang-format?
I am using clang-format to format my C++ code. However, I want to align preprocessor directives (including the # sign) with the surrounding code blocks. Currently, clang-format aligns the directives based on their own rules, which doesn't match the alignment of my functions, loops, and conditional statements.
Here's an example of what I currently have:
#pragma region WIFI {
#ifdef __CONFIG_WIFI__

void wifi_handler()
{
  switch(wifi.connectionMode)
  {
    case WIFI_STA:
    {
  #ifdef __CONFIG_WEBSOCKET__
      if(WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED && webSocketClient.isConnected()) webSocketClient.loop();
  #endif
      break;
    }
    case WIFI_AP:
    {
  #ifdef __CONFIG_FTP__
      ftpSrv.handleFTP();
  #endif

  #ifdef __CONFIG_WEB__
      webServer.handleClient();
  #endif

  #ifdef __CONFIG_WEBSOCKET__
      webSocketServer.loop();
  #endif
      break;
    }
  }
}

#endif
#pragma endregion }

And here's what I want to achieve:
#pragma region WIFI {
#ifdef __CONFIG_WIFI__

void wifi_handler()
{
  switch(wifi.connectionMode)
  {
    case WIFI_STA:
    {
      #ifdef __CONFIG_WEBSOCKET__
      if(WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED && webSocketClient.isConnected()) webSocketClient.loop();
      #endif
      break;
    }
    case WIFI_AP:
    {
      #ifdef __CONFIG_FTP__
      ftpSrv.handleFTP();
      #endif
      
      #ifdef __CONFIG_WEB__
      webServer.handleClient();
      #endif
      
      #ifdef __CONFIG_WEBSOCKET__
      webSocketServer.loop();
      #endif
      break;
    }
  }
}

#endif
#pragma endregion }

I've tried various clang-format options, but none of them seem to affect the alignment of the # sign. Here is my current .clang-format configuration:
---
BasedOnStyle: LLVM
AccessModifierOffset: -2
AlignAfterOpenBracket: Align
AlignArrayOfStructures: Right
AlignConsecutiveAssignments:
  Enabled: true
  AcrossEmptyLines: false
  AcrossComments: false
  AlignCompound: true
  PadOperators: true
AlignConsecutiveBitFields:
  Enabled: true
  AcrossEmptyLines: false
  AcrossComments: false
  AlignCompound: true
  PadOperators: true
AlignConsecutiveDeclarations:
  Enabled: true
  AcrossEmptyLines: false
  AcrossComments: false
  AlignCompound: true
  PadOperators: true
AlignConsecutiveMacros:
  Enabled: true
  AcrossEmptyLines: false
  AcrossComments: false
  AlignCompound: true
  PadOperators: true
AlignConsecutiveShortCaseStatements:
  Enabled: true
  AcrossEmptyLines: false
  AcrossComments: true
  AlignCaseColons: true
AlignEscapedNewlines: Left
AlignOperands: AlignAfterOperator
AlignTrailingComments:
  Kind: Always
  OverEmptyLines: 0
AllowAllArgumentsOnNextLine: false
AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine: false
AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine: Always
AllowShortCaseLabelsOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortEnumsOnASingleLine: true
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: All
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: AllIfsAndElse
AllowShortLambdasOnASingleLine: All
AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine: true
AlwaysBreakAfterDefinitionReturnType: None
AlwaysBreakAfterReturnType: None
AlwaysBreakBeforeMultilineStrings: false
AlwaysBreakTemplateDeclarations: MultiLine
AttributeMacros:
  - __capability
BinPackArguments: false
BinPackParameters: false
BitFieldColonSpacing: Both
BraceWrapping:
  AfterCaseLabel: true
  AfterClass: true
  AfterControlStatement: Always
  AfterEnum: true
  AfterFunction: true
  AfterNamespace: true
  AfterObjCDeclaration: false
  AfterStruct: true
  AfterUnion: true
  AfterExternBlock: true
  BeforeCatch: true
  BeforeElse: true
  BeforeLambdaBody: true
  BeforeWhile: true
  IndentBraces: false
  SplitEmptyFunction: true
  SplitEmptyRecord: true
  SplitEmptyNamespace: true
BreakAfterAttributes: Never
BreakAfterJavaFieldAnnotations: false
BreakArrays: true
BreakBeforeBinaryOperators: None
BreakBeforeBraces: Custom
BreakBeforeConceptDeclarations: Allowed
BreakBeforeInlineASMColon: OnlyMultiline
BreakBeforeTernaryOperators: false
BreakConstructorInitializers: AfterColon
BreakInheritanceList: AfterComma
BreakStringLiterals: false
ColumnLimit: 180
CommentPragmas: "^ IWYU pragma:"
CompactNamespaces: false
ConstructorInitializerIndentWidth: 2
ContinuationIndentWidth: 2
Cpp11BracedListStyle: true
DerivePointerAlignment: false
DisableFormat: false
EmptyLineAfterAccessModifier: Always
EmptyLineBeforeAccessModifier: LogicalBlock
ExperimentalAutoDetectBinPacking: false
FixNamespaceComments: true
ForEachMacros:
  - foreach
  - Q_FOREACH
  - BOOST_FOREACH
IfMacros:
  - KJ_IF_MAYBE
IncludeBlocks: Preserve
IncludeCategories:
  - Regex: ^"(llvm|llvm-c|clang|clang-c)/
    Priority: 2
    SortPriority: 0
    CaseSensitive: false
  - Regex: ^(<|"(gtest|gmock|isl|json)/)
    Priority: 3
    SortPriority: 0
    CaseSensitive: false
  - Regex: .*
    Priority: 1
    SortPriority: 0
    CaseSensitive: false
IncludeIsMainRegex: (Test)?$
IncludeIsMainSourceRegex: ""
IndentAccessModifiers: false
IndentCaseBlocks: false
IndentCaseLabels: true
IndentExternBlock: AfterExternBlock
IndentGotoLabels: true
IndentPPDirectives: BeforeHash
IndentRequiresClause: true
IndentWidth: 2
IndentWrappedFunctionNames: true
InsertBraces: false
InsertNewlineAtEOF: true
InsertTrailingCommas: None
IntegerLiteralSeparator:
  Binary: 0
  BinaryMinDigits: 0
  Decimal: 0
  DecimalMinDigits: 0
  Hex: 0
  HexMinDigits: 0
JavaScriptQuotes: Leave
JavaScriptWrapImports: true
KeepEmptyLinesAtEOF: true
KeepEmptyLinesAtTheStartOfBlocks: true
LambdaBodyIndentation: Signature
Language: Cpp
LineEnding: DeriveLF
MacroBlockBegin: ""
MacroBlockEnd: ""
MaxEmptyLinesToKeep: 1
NamespaceIndentation: Inner
ObjCBinPackProtocolList: Auto
ObjCBlockIndentWidth: 2
ObjCBreakBeforeNestedBlockParam: true
ObjCSpaceAfterProperty: false
ObjCSpaceBeforeProtocolList: true
PPIndentWidth: -1
PackConstructorInitializers: NextLine
PenaltyBreakAssignment: 2
PenaltyBreakBeforeFirstCallParameter: 19
PenaltyBreakComment: 300
PenaltyBreakFirstLessLess: 120
PenaltyBreakOpenParenthesis: 0
PenaltyBreakString: 1000
PenaltyBreakTemplateDeclaration: 10
PenaltyExcessCharacter: 1000000
PenaltyIndentedWhitespace: 0
PenaltyReturnTypeOnItsOwnLine: 60
PointerAlignment: Right
QualifierAlignment: Leave
ReferenceAlignment: Pointer
ReflowComments: false
RemoveBracesLLVM: false
RemoveParentheses: Leave
RemoveSemicolon: false
RequiresClausePosition: SingleLine
RequiresExpressionIndentation: OuterScope
SeparateDefinitionBlocks: Leave
ShortNamespaceLines: 1
SortIncludes: Never
SortJavaStaticImport: Before
SortUsingDeclarations: LexicographicNumeric
SpaceAfterCStyleCast: false
SpaceAfterLogicalNot: false
SpaceAfterTemplateKeyword: true
SpaceAroundPointerQualifiers: Default
SpaceBeforeAssignmentOperators: true
SpaceBeforeCaseColon: false
SpaceBeforeCpp11BracedList: false
SpaceBeforeCtorInitializerColon: true
SpaceBeforeInheritanceColon: true
SpaceBeforeJsonColon: false
SpaceBeforeParens: Custom
SpaceBeforeParensOptions:
  AfterControlStatements: false
  AfterForeachMacros: true
  AfterFunctionDeclarationName: false
  AfterFunctionDefinitionName: false
  AfterIfMacros: true
  AfterOverloadedOperator: false
  AfterRequiresInClause: true
  AfterRequiresInExpression: true
  BeforeNonEmptyParentheses: false
SpaceBeforeRangeBasedForLoopColon: false
SpaceBeforeSquareBrackets: false
SpaceInEmptyBlock: false
SpacesBeforeTrailingComments: 1
SpacesInAngles: Never
SpacesInContainerLiterals: false
SpacesInLineCommentPrefix:
  Minimum: 1
  Maximum: -1
SpacesInParens: Never
SpacesInParensOptions:
  InConditionalStatements: false
  InCStyleCasts: false
  InEmptyParentheses: false
  Other: false
SpacesInSquareBrackets: false
Standard: Latest
StatementAttributeLikeMacros:
  - Q_EMIT
StatementMacros:
  - Q_UNUSED
  - QT_REQUIRE_VERSION
TabWidth: 8
UseTab: Never
VerilogBreakBetweenInstancePorts: true
WhitespaceSensitiveMacros:
  - BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE
  - CF_SWIFT_NAME
  - NS_SWIFT_NAME
  - PP_STRINGIZE
  - STRINGIZE
BracedInitializerIndentWidth: 2


Despite these settings, the # sign does not align as I would like it to. Is there a way to configure clang-format to achieve this alignment, or do I need to use an additional tool or script to format my code in this way?
Any advice on how to get the preprocessor directives to align properly would be greatly appreciated. If a script is required, an example of such a script would also be very helpful. Thank you!
(I'm attaching screenshots of my code before and after formatting to illustrate the issue.)
Before formatting the code
After formatting the code

I haven't found an answer to this.  Crappy workaround:  Enclose preprocessor directives in empty block comments.
The following gets indented at the same level as surrounding code.
/**/ #if DEBUGLVL > 0 /**/

/**/ #endif /**/

